# how use EnableSignOutPrompt?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identity, identityserver4

I'm using Identityserver4. Do you know how to use "EnableSignOutPrompt"? I can not understand how to do it.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `ShowLogoutPrompt` to true in AccountOptions class under services in Identity server!

**Update** check this [sample class](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity/Quickstart/Account/AccountOptions.cs) on github

Comment: Would you be able to add more detail on where to specify this please?